# Accessing Unity package version at runtime

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm working on a custom analytics system (which is a custom package) and it would be super helpful to know which version of this package is integrated in the unity app when I'm looking into the data.

Is there any quick solution to retrieve the pacakge version at runtime ?

Comment: why not hardcode it somewhere like `const string VERSION = "1.2.3.4"` ? You can get the version only within the Editor itself via [`PackageInfo.version`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PackageManager.PackageInfo-version.html)

Comment: @derHugo thanks for the idea, but since the tool is still in an active development phase with a lot of releases, I'd like to avoid this manual trick, which will lead at some point to a mistake, I'm sure ;)

Answer (score 0):

As said what you could do is using a ScriptableObject just for storing the version for the runtime later.

You could e.g. do it like

```
// See https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/PlatformDependentCompilation.html
#if UNITY_EDITOR
using UnityEditor;
#endif;

public class PackageVersion : ScriptableObject
{
    // See https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/HideInInspector.html
    [HideInInspector] public string Version;

#if UNITY_EDITOR
    // Called automatically after open Unity and each recompilation
    // See https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/InitializeOnLoadMethodAttribute.html
    [InitializeOnLoadMethod]
    private static void Init()
    {
        // See https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Compilation.CompilationPipeline-compilationFinished.html
        // Removing the callback before adding it makes sure it is only added once at a time
        CompilationPipeline.compilationFinished -= OnCompilationFinished;
        CompilationPipeline.compilationFinished += OnCompilationFinished;
    }

    private static void OnCompilationFinished()
    {
        // First get the path of the Package
        // This is quite easy since this script itself belongs to your package's assemblies
        var assembly = typeof(PackageVersion).Assembly;

        // See https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PackageManager.PackageInfo.FindForAssembly.html
        var packageInfo = PackageManager.PackageInfo.FindForAssembly();

        // Finally we have access to the version!
        var version = packageInfo.version;

        // Now to the ScriptableObject instance
        // Try to find the first instance
        // See https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AssetDatabase.FindAssets.html
        // See https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PackageManager.PackageInfo-assetPath.html
        var guid = AssetDataBase.FindAssets($"t:{nameof(PackageVersion)}", packageInfo.assetPath). FirstOrDefault();
        PackageVersion asset;
        if(!string.isNullOrWhiteSpace(guid))
        {
            // See https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AssetDatabase.GUIDToAssetPath.html
            var path = AssetDatabase.GUIDToAssetPath(guid);
            // See https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AssetDatabase.LoadAssetAtPath.html
            asset = AssetDatabase.LoadAssetAtPath<PackageVersion>(path);                          
        }
        else
        {

            // None found -> create a new one
            asset = ScriptableObject.CreateInstance<PackageVersion>();
            asset.name = nameof(PackageVersion);
            // make it non editable via the Inspector
            // See https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/HideFlags.NotEditable.html
            asset.hideFlags = HideFlags.NotEditable;

            // Store the asset as actually asset
            // See https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AssetDatabase.CreateAsset.html
            AssetDataBase.CreateAsset(asset, $"{packageInfo.assetPath}/{nameof(PackageVersion)}");
        }

        asset.Version = version;

        // See https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EditorUtility.SetDirty.html
        EditorUtility.SetDirty(asset);
    }
#endif
}
```

Now wherever needed you can just reference that `PackageVersion` object and access the version on runtime.

---

*Note: Typed on smartphone but I hope the idea gets clear*